Перевод числа в название месяца
Как при помощи js взять из тега <span id="first">1</span> число 1, преобразовать в название месяца (январь) и вернуть это название обратно в этот же самый тег вместо числа  <span id="first">Январь</span> и так далее все 12 месяцев? Спасибо.


Как при помощи js взять из тега 1 число 1, преобразовать в название месяца (январь) и вернуть это название обратно в этот же самый тег вместо числа

Например так...


const a = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь']

first.textContent = a[first.textContent - 1]
<span id="first">1</span>




Можно ли как-то усовершенствовать скрипт, чтобы он изменял названия месяца при изменении цифры в теге, так как цифра в теге не статична , а переодически меняется. Получается, что скрипт отработал один раз, а дальше при изменении цифры ничего не происходит. Спасибо

@Siarhei789654, так пусть кто менял ту цифру, запустит и этот скрипт...
